# How Can I Roll The Status Bar Background In My Xamarin UI Tests?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nunit, xamarin.uitest

[this is the status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5rd7.png)

I tried to do actions on his Id without any response like:
app.tap, app.DragAndDrop ...

but from the REPL screen I managed to flash him:
[Repl Screen Of The App Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDtpp.png)

please help me :)

Comment: What do you mean by roll the status bar background? Do you mean defining a different background color for it? If so, then this link might help: https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/08/20/dynamically-changing-the-status-bar-appearance-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I mean to open the status bar